# Viewing graph in PDF

Tags: pdf, graph

How can I show a bar graph or a pie chart in PDF? Is there any way to do this with `Zend_PDF` class? Please help me.

Comment: Can you give more information about how the chart has been created (language, platform etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The [Zend_Pdf](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.introduction.html) component is a PDF (Portable Document Format) manipulation engine. It can load, create, modify and save documents.

It's a lower level module and just includes

- Different drawing primitives (lines, rectangles, polygons, circles, ellipses and sectors).

No charts. [At this sitepoint article](http://articles.sitepoint.com/print/generate-pdfs-php) you'll find a couple of php/pdf examples. An alternative would be to generate charts in a different library and then just use Zend_Pdf to assemble the document.

Some neat non-php charting libraries:

- http://nubyonrails.com/pages/gruff
- http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/
- http://lovelight.co.nz/blog/2009/01/integrating-google-charts-into-a-prawn-pdf/
- http://code.enthought.com/chaco/